# Convert scanf to cin

Tags: c++, scanf, cin

I am reading the following code: [evaluate.cpp](http://cgi.cse.unsw.edu.au/~xic/cgi-bin/evaluate.cpp) from the following website: [neural networr](http://cgi.cse.unsw.edu.au/~xic/digits/)
I am trying to convert the following piece of code from `scanf` to `cin`:

### **c:**

```
 for(int a=0;a<64;a++) {
    if(scanf("%f+", &NNetwork.InputUnits[a])!=1) {
        printf("Input Error!<br>\n"); return -1;
    }
}
```

---

**c++:**

```
for(int a=0;a<64;a++) {
       cin >> NNetwork.InputUnits[a];
       if (NNetwork.InputUnits[a] != 1) {
            cout << "Input Erro"; 
             return -1;
        }
    }
```

---

Is the following conversion correct?

Comment: "Is the following conversion correct?" Did it compile? Did you run it? Did it do the same thing as the scanf version?

Comment: It would seem to me that your first step should be making sure you understand exactly what the original code does - which, by comments below, it seems you have not done. It will be difficult to convert any code from one language to another if you don't understand the code you are converting - it can't just be done by transliteration.

Comment: As Borgleader said, you should be able to test the code yourself to see if it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translation is not correct.

- You are not accounting for the '+' in the input.
- The original comparison checks for the number of arguments scanned by
  `scanf`.

Here is a more correct translation:

```
    for (unsigned int a = 0; a < 64; ++a)
    {
      bool failure = true;
      if (cin >> NNetwork.InputUnits[a])
      {
        // Need to scan for the '+'.
        char plus;
        if (cin >> plus)
        {
// edit 1: added checking for '+' character after reading.
          if (plus == '+')
          {
            failure = false;
          }
        }
      }
      if (failure)
      {
        cerr << "Input Error!<br>\n";
        return -1;
      }
    }
```

Comment: You probably need to also (at the very least) verify that `plus == '+'` after you've read it.

Comment: @twalberg:  Thanks for the reminder, I forgot to put that in.

Answer (score 0):

cin.fail() can be used to check the status.

This check looks wrong:
if (NNetwork.InputUnits[a] != 1)